# Can't install miniconda, issues with 'GLIBC_2.10'?

Tags: bash, installation, conda, glibc, miniconda

I'm trying to set-up a new cluster so I thought I'd install miniconda to handle my installs and environments.

I've downloaded Miniconda3

then

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

yes to the user agreement, 
confirm location to be in the bin directory
but it spits out

```
PREFIX=/pub38/youseuf/bin/miniconda
Unpacking payload ...
[13516] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIYzJSe2/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: 
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by 
/tmp/_MEIYzJSe2/libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
[13519] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIPTBxrk/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: 
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by 
/tmp/_MEIPTBxrk/libpython3.7m.so.1.0)
```

Do I not have an up to date 'GLIBC'?
I'm running python 2.7.3 but cannot seem to update to python 3.7 without conda which is what I'm used to.

Sorry if this question is trivial to some of you.

Comment: "Do I not have an up to date 'GLIBC'?" -- that's an understatement. GLIBC-2.10 was released 11 years ago and is *ancient*, and you don't even have that (you have something older). Current version is 2.31: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline

Answer (score 1):

Miniconda3 was compiled with glibc version 2.10

SO you can either:

a. recompile the program with your system's version of glibc OR
  b. install a newer version of glibc and then run the install script again.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: I found out that the system was running Debian 5 enviroment and that I can change to a more up to date one by using 'chos 7' to change to Debian 7. This had an up to date GLIBC. Thanks for the reply though!